# How to get Log4perl rotating my logs daily?

Tags: linux, perl, logging, log4perl

I'm reading up on [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.40/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm) and want to try and use it for simple log management of my Perl scripts running on a Linux box. I've also read up on `newsyslog` and `logrotate` but want to use Log4perl if at all possible.

I'm trying to configure the `/etc/log4perl.conf` file so that it:

- Defines a `widget` logger (`INFO` level) that will write all output to `/opt/myapp/logs/myapp-<datetime>.log`, where `<datetime>` is a date/time formatted string like `2012-12-20`
- This `myapp-<datetime>.log` file needs to be rotated daily (preferably at midnight), where the old file is deleted, and a new file is created with `<datetime> + 1`. For instance, `myapp-2012-12-20.log` would be replaced with `myapp-2012-12-21.log`, etc.

Here's my best attempt which I believe is close, but is still missing some configuration:

```
#####/etc/log4perl.conf############################################################
log4perl.logger.widget                      = INFO, MyAppLogAppender

log4perl.appender.MyAppLogAppender          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.MyAppLogAppender.filename = /opt/myapp/logs/myapp-???.log
log4perl.appender.MyAppLogAppender.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout
###################################################################################
```

**How do I configure `log4perl.appender.MyAppLogAppender` to rotate once a day, delete the old file, and create a new one with a correct timestamp?** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example of a Log::Log4perl configuration file, defining a daily rollover at midnight (date pattern yyyy-MM-dd), keeping a maximum of 5 saved logfiles around, at WARN level, and dumping everything to screen:

```
log4perl.logger                         = TRACE, Screen, Logfile

log4perl.appender.Logfile               = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.Logfile.Threshold     = WARN
log4perl.appender.Logfile.filename      = test.log
log4perl.appender.Logfile.max           = 5
log4perl.appender.Logfile.DatePattern   = yyyy-MM-dd
log4perl.appender.Logfile.TZ            = PST
log4perl.appender.Logfile.layout        = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout 
log4perl.appender.Logfile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %m %n

log4perl.appender.Screen                = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.Screen.stderr         = 0
log4perl.appender.Screen.utf8           = 1
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout         = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout::Multiline
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout.ConversionPattern = [%p] %m %n
```

(reference: https://metacpan.org/module/Log::Log4perl::FAQ#How-can-I-roll-over-my-logfiles-automatically-at-midnight-)

Comment: Awesome @creaktive (+1) - one more thing: what's the significance of the "\" after `log4perl.appender.Logfile.layout`? Can I remove it and just place the value beneath (`Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout`) on the same line? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I assume that *any* Perl script using `Log4perl` can then use this `widget` logger?

Comment: Sorry, I promise this is the last followup: it looks like you're configuring the `WARN` level to use the `LogFile` appender. Is there a way to attach a logger to an appender for all log levels (WARN or otherwise)? Thanks again!!

Comment: @HeineyBehinds: updated the example so it logs WARN messages to rotating logfile and prints everything on screen (TRACE is the most verbose level). The `\` character was line break marker, as in shell. Not necessary, at all :)

Comment: Hmmm... I really *hate* to ask this because you've been so helpful so far (I wish I could upvote you more!) but what happens if I have other Perl scripts that want to log to other files besides just `test.log`? Once I can see the relationship of loggers, appenders and log files, I think all the lightbulbs will turn on! Thanks again so much for all the help!

Comment: No problem, @HeineyBehinds! Unfortunately, I've never used the same `Log4perl.conf` to route messages to different files. But, AFAIK, that's what [Log4perl categories](https://metacpan.org/module/Log::Log4perl#Categories) are all about.

Comment: Figured it out - you just list different logger via `log4perl.logger.<X>` where `<X>` is the name of your logger. You associate a log level and an appender with each logger as your example shows. Then you just add a configuration for each appender, and on each configuration, you specify a different file name. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a gotcha in `Log::Dispatch::FileRotate`, if your daily job is run later in the day (say 23:00) and takes 2h (so ends at about 01:00), the log rotation will never happens with a "day" pattern like :

```
log4perl.appender.Logfile.DatePattern   = yyyy-MM-dd
```

A simple workaround is to use an "hourly" pattern like this :

```
log4perl.appender.Logfile.DatePattern   = yyyy-MM-dd-HH
```

So when the next run starts at 23:00, the log file get rotated as more than one hour has passed.